Can I ask question that had been asked in other forum by myself?
I had asked for help in podman discussion on Github (see the post here) but no luck getting an answer. Is it OK to copy the content and ask the question here?

Stack Exchange site rules don't allow the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites; however there are no rules relating to the same question asked on very different sites (I just suggest you should also comment that's it was asked elsewhere & provide link; as many of use multiple sites thus see the same question numerous times).  The question must be about a Ubuntu problem (on a release that is in standard support; not ESM/EOL etc) & fit site rules ; see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   FYI:  This is a Q&A site & not a forum ; https://ubuntuforums.org/ is Ubuntu Forums

FYI: Am I allowed to indicate crosspost links in my questions on Stack Exchange?

Yes, you can ask a question here on Ask Ubuntu that you've already asked on some other site, assuming it's on topic here.
In your case, there's no problem, but if you had already asked on another Stack Exchange site, you would have to be careful because the network discourages cross-posting. If your question gets no attention, quietly deleting it and posting on another site may go well. Alternatively, you can flag and ask for migration to another site, but moderators have to decide whether or not the migration is a good idea and many such requests are declined. However, there is a slight chance that flagging for migration will draw enough attention to the question for someone to answer it! :)
